# Georeferenced overlay not being displayed properly on Leaflet

Tags: qgis, leaflet, georeferencing, epsg

I have an image of Europe and Asia with an unknown projection that I want to display on Leaflet. So I georeferenced it on QGIS with EPSG:3857.

The result looks pretty good. For example I get the following points/coordinates:

- Northernmost point of France: 51.07, 2.53
- Northernmost point of Hokkaido: 45.46, 141.89
- Cape Town: -33.92, 18.46
- Southernmost point of India: 8.09, 77.46

The result matches the world [shapefile](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php) I have downloaded.

So, still from QGIS, I saved the output in a tif file. Which I then converted to PNG with:

```
gdal_translate -of PNG  -co worldfile=yes file.tif file.png
```

Here is what gdalinfo tells me about file.tif:

```
Size is 1269, 637
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed ellipse",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-27.056867121684334,81.529534762914096)
Pixel Size = (0.217559535863945,-0.217559535863945)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -27.0568671,  81.5295348) (  0d 0' 0.88"W,  0d 0' 2.64"N)
Lower Left  ( -27.0568671, -57.0558896) (  0d 0' 0.88"W,  0d 0' 1.85"S)
Upper Right (     249.026,      81.530) (  0d 0' 8.05"E,  0d 0' 2.64"N)
Lower Right (     249.026,     -57.056) (  0d 0' 8.05"E,  0d 0' 1.85"S)
Center      ( 110.9846584,  12.2368226) (  0d 0' 3.59"E,  0d 0' 0.40"N)
Band 1 Block=1269x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=1269x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=1269x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Everything is looking good. So I added it on Leaflet with:

```
var bounds= L.latLngBounds({lat: 81.5295348, lng: -27.0568671}, {lat: -57.056, lng: 249.026});
L.imageOverlay('file.png', bounds, {}).addTo(map);
```

On the map, the corners are all at the right place, but between them, it's not projected as I was expecting and the overlay not match the EPSG:3857 projection of Leaflet.

Which step did I fail?

By the way here is what I have on Leaflet: [http://i.imgur.com/2O3k4sh.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/2O3k4sh.jpg)

And here is what I have on QGIS: https://i.imgur.com/nRXC9ft.png

Comment: those corners look like 4326 not 3857

Comment: How so? By the way here is what I have on Leaflet: https://i.imgur.com/2O3k4sh.png And here is what I have on QGIS: https://i.imgur.com/nRXC9ft.png

Comment: because they are very small unless you are mapping Null Island

Comment: Ok I got it and everything's working now. Noobie mistake. Thanks for putting me on the track.